# Typopscript hide subtitle if empty

Tags: typoscript, typo3-10.x

I just can't understand how typoscript if constructs work.

what I would like to do is display the subtitle of a page only if present. I tried with the if clause of the fluidetemplate, in this way, but it doesn't work (always print `<p class="subTitle">` tag also if no subtitle is present):

```
<f:if condition="page : subtitle !=''">
    <p class="subTitle">{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.pageSubTitle')->f:format.raw()}</p>
</f:if>
```

So I wanted to try using typoscritp but I can't figure it out.

This is the current situation:

```
lib.pageSubTitle = TEXT
lib.pageSubTitle.data = page: subtitle
lib.pageSubTitle.wrap = <p class = "subTitle"> | </p>
```

I would like, in case of absence of subtile, let `lib.pageSubTitle` was "emptied", so as not to have an empty `<p>` object that increases the margin between the title and the body of the page. Otherwise i want to wrap subtitle only if is not empty.

I hope I have explained my problem well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fluid is a bit too complex, you can just use

```
<f:if condition="{page.subtitle}">
    <p class="subTitle">{page.subtitle}</p>
</f:if>
```

If you want to use TypoScript, you can use the option `stdWrap.required = 1` to make your TypoScript work

```
lib.pageSubTitle = TEXT
lib.pageSubTitle {
    data = page: subtitle
    stdWrap.required = 1
    stdWrap.wrap = <p class = "subTitle"> | </p>
}
```